# ORDER BY performance when executing a query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, hibernate, sql-order-by

I have been working on a Spring application that connects to an Oracle database.

After three years, the amount of records in our tables are so much bigger that the response time of queries is so bad and our customer is dissatisfied.

So, I searched and [got this URL for Oracle performance tuning](http://www.dataintegration.ninja/32-tips-for-oracle-sql-query-writing-and-performance-tuning/).

The factor's 22 of this URL tells to NOT use ORDER BY in the query when the response time is important. So, if I omit ORDER BY from my query, the response time is more than half than with ORDER BY.

But I can not omit ORDER BY from my query because the customer needs sorting.

How do I fix my problem, so that I have ordering and a response time?

Comment: you should update your question add  a tables  schema ,, the query .. and the execution plan

Comment: There are consultants who make a fine living by doing nothing but Oracle performance tuning: they could not do so if tuning was a matter of *do this* or *don't do that* in every case. Search `[oracle]+[performance]` on this site, and you'll find us giving the same advice to Seekers like you. Performance is about specifics: the exact query, the actual execution plan, the volume and skew of data, the environment itself. Without such details your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Anyone that says simply 'don't use ORDER BY' is missing the point. Performance tuning is about optimizing your query to fulfil your requirement as efficiently as possible. Unfortunately the answer to a performance question is almost always 'Depends'. Depends on all the @APC said as well as your hardware profile and network. That's why performance experts charge a lot of money - its hard.

Answer (score 3):

one of the best  sulotion that Markus Winand metion in his blog that is using pipelined order by and it's detail in in the this [link](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/top-n-queries)

Answer (score 0):

> The factor's 22 of this URL tell that DO NOT use order by in the query
> when the response time is important, I omit order by from my query for
> this the response time is more half than the first

On the Internet, you should always question every advice you get.

In order for the ORDER BY clause to be fast, you need to use the right index. Make sure the sorting is done using a database index, therefore avoiding a full-table scan or an explicit sort operation. When in doubt, just search for SQL performance issues on [Markus Winand's Use the Index Luke site](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by) or, even better, read his [SQL Performance Explained](http://sql-performance-explained.com/) book.

So, you should make sure that the Buffer Pool is properly configured and you have enough RAM to hold the data working set and indexes as well.

If you really have huge data (e.g. billions of records), then you should use partitioning. Otherwise, for tens or hundreds of millions of records, you could just scale vertically using more RAM.

Also, make sure you use compact data types. For example, don't store an Enum ordinal value into a 32-bit integer value since a single byte would probably be more than enough to store all Enum values you might use.